# component state updates in dev tools but not when I call this.state afterwards

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component where I use the material-ui controlled table example for a datatable that keeps the index of the currently selected row in state. This is working fine and I can see the state updating correctly in react dev tools. However, when updatePick is called, this.state.selected is not returning the updated value.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: [],
    }
  }

  isSelected = (index) => {
    return this.state.selected.indexOf(index) !== -1;
  }

  handleRowSelection = (selectedRows) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: selectedRows,
    })
  }


  updatePick = () => {
    console.log(this.state.selected);  //Shows []
    console.log(this.state.selected[0]);  //undefined
    this.props.updateTodaysPick(this.props.players[this.state.selected[0]]);
  }
```

React Dev tools shows my state to be
selected: [1]

I've been researching, so here are a couple things I can rule out.

1. binding this to the function didn't help. My understanding is that using the arrow functions negates the necessity for this.
2. I know that setState doesn't happen synchronously. The updatePick method is not being fired right after, but must be toggled separately, so the state has had enough time to update.

Here's my render function

```
render() {

    var players = this.props.players.slice(0, 40).map((player, index) => {
          return (
            <TableRow key={index} selected={this.isSelected(index)}>
              <TableRowColumn></TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{player.first_name} {player.last_name}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{player.team}</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          )
      }
    )

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="submit"><RaisedButton label="Update Player" secondary={true} onClick={this.updatePick} /></div>
        <Table onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection} preScanRows={false} fixedHeader={true}>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {players}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow - hopefully it's up to snuff.

---

EDIT: This was a material-ui table setting that deselects the row when the table component loses focus (clicking the submit button). You can set this in a prop for the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the default behavior of [`Material UI Table`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table).

Your `Table` is [`blurring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) every time your `<RaisedButton/>` is `clicked`.

As a result, `this.handleRowSelection()` is being called with no rows selected, thereby clearing your `this.state.selection`.

To prevent your `Table` from `blurring`: use `onMouseDown` rather than `onClick` to call `this.updatePick()`:

```
<div className="submit"><RaisedButton label="Update Player" secondary={true} onMouseDown={this.updatePick} /></div>
```

Be sure to then fire `preventDefault()` on the `event` param to prevent the `blur`:

```
// Update Pick.
updatePick = (event) => {

  // Prevent Table from blurring.
  event.preventDefault() 

  // Update Todays Pick.
  this.props.updateTodaysPick(this.props.players[this.state.selected[0]]) 
}
```

Comment: True, but I don't want to hit the DB every time they select someone, I want them to be able to browse, change their selection if they'd like, and then submit it.

Comment: Ok. Based on this [Material UI doc ref](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table): I'm guessing that `clicking` your submit button [`blurs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) your `Table` and thereby clears `this.state.selection`. The solution is to not `blur` the table. The trick is to use `onMouseDown` and `preventDefault()` rather than `onClick`. I've revised my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: Ah I see the blur effect - good catch, although I found a better solution.  The material-ui tableBody accepts a prop to toggle this behavior.

Thanks!!

Comment: Aaahh true `deselectOnClickaway={false}`. Good catch.